# State change detected only when screen is tapped

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-ios

I have a few TouchOpacity components which fire a function when pressed. This function retrieves data and then sets state.

```
const Summary = () => {
  const [timeSpan, setTimeSpan] = useState('Day');
  const [derivedData, setDerivedData] = useState({
    chartTimeSpan: 'Day',
    sales: [],
    totalSales: 0,
    orders: 0,
    logins: 0,
  });

  const _fetchSummary = async (timeSpan) => {
    console.log(`_fetchSummary HIT : ${timeSpan}`);
    try {
      const res = await axios.get(`/summary/${timeSpan.toLowerCase()}`);
      const { loginCount, orderQty, sales, totalSales } = res.data;
      await setDerivedData({
        chartTimeSpan: timeSpan,
        sales,
        totalSales,
        orders: orderQty,
        logins: loginCount,
      });
      await setTimeSpan(timeSpan);
      console.log(timeSpan, loginCount, orderQty, sales, totalSales);
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  };

  const _switchTimeSpan = (newTimeSpan) => {
    console.log(`TimeSpan : ${timeSpan}`);
    console.log(`NewTimeSpan : ${newTimeSpan}`);
    if (timeSpan !== newTimeSpan) {
      _fetchSummary(newTimeSpan);
    }
  };

  const { chartTimeSpan, sales, totalSales, orders, logins } = derivedData;
  console.log(derivedData);
  return (
    <>
  <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => _switchTimeSpan('Day')}>
    <Text style={dropDownItemStyle}>Day</Text>
  </TouchableOpacity>
  <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => _switchTimeSpan('Week')}>
    <Text style={dropDownItemStyle}>Week</Text>
  </TouchableOpacity>
  <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => _switchTimeSpan('Month')}>
    <Text style={dropDownItemStyle}>Month</Text>
  </TouchableOpacity>
  <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => _switchTimeSpan('Year')}>
    <Text style={dropDownItemStyle}>Year</Text>
  </TouchableOpacity>
    </>
  );
};
```

Everything works fine. The data gets fetched when i click the buttons too. However state doesn't get updated after the data is fetched. I know this because *console.log(derivedData);* just above the return statement doesn't run. When i tap anywhere on the screen the *console.log(derivedData);* gives the expected output. Note that i have not set any function which detects this event when i touch the screen.

> I have used the derivedData in some other components but did not include those for simplicity sake.

Comment: This might happen because your component is stateless. I suggest you to create your component as a `PureComponent`. Here is a link that i think it might help your question [link](https://60devs.com/pure-component-in-react.html)

Comment: @firats I am using react hooks. Would you happen to know why the state isn't getting updated ?

Comment: Does the issue persist when you use 

useEffect(() => {
  console.log(derivedData);
});

Comment: @HaswinVidanage the useEffect doesn't fire as soon as I press the TouchOpacity. It only fires when i tap the screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was caused because I have included the following lines of code in App.js file.

```
XMLHttpRequest = GLOBAL.originalXMLHttpRequest
  ? GLOBAL.originalXMLHttpRequest
  : GLOBAL.XMLHttpRequest;

// fetch logger
global._fetch = fetch;
global.fetch = (uri, options, ...args) => (global._fetch(uri, options, ...args)
  .then((response) => {
    console.log('Fetch', { request: { uri, options, ...args }, response });
    return response;
  }));
```

The above code allows to detect the network requests. I don't know why but although the above code shows the network requests it also delays the data passed from requests to go into the component unless the screen is tapped.

Commenting out the above lines in production lets the code work as it should.

Answer (score 0):

The `console.log(derivedData)` will be run, when the components need to be rerendered. This depends on the injected state and props variables. Since state variables are not used in JSX, there is no need to rerender the component and log the new `derivedData`.

You could bypass this by using `import { useEffect } from 'react'`. Try to log derived data with:

```
useEffect(() => {
  console.log(derivedData);
});
```

Comment: I am using it those states in another component which I have not mentioned for simplicity sake. Also i am console logging just to see the state change take place. Also why does the state change occur when i tap the screen instead ?

Comment: Do you have other touch events listened to, or just the ones in the code?

Comment: I dont have a single touch event other than those touch opacity buttons. And the state gets updated no matter where i tap on screen, even if it has no onPress functions.